# Dask error: Grouper for <something> not 1-dimensional

Tags: python, pandas, dask, sparse-matrix

I have created a pivot table in Dask and now I am trying to convert it back to a Pandas dataframe, since I want to create a sparse matrix. I am getting the above-mentioned error when I run the `compute()` function since it is necessary to create a categorical column in Dask to use the `pivot_table()` function.

I have no experience with Dask, used it because making a Pivot Table in Pandas for a dataframe with ~800K rows is a nightmare.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you share a reproducer, or at least some code snippet?